# Android custom listview

Tags: android

Hi i've got a custom listview with a text view and a button in each row.
Im having trouble trying to use the buttons . Each button will fire a different intent. This is the xml file for the list view rows.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/widget29"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Remind me"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text12"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ff99ccff"
  android:text="Text view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then i have another xml file which simply contains the list view in a linear layout.

This is my custom array class.

```
public class customArray extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
 int resource;

 public customArray(Context cont, int _resource, List<String> items) {
      super (cont, _resource,items);
      resource = _resource;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      RelativeLayout rl;

     String prod = getItem(position);
      if (convertView == null) {
           rl = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
           LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           vi.inflate(resource, rl, true);
      } else {
           rl = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
      }
     TextView t1 = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.text12);
     t1.setText(prod);
      Button b1 = (Button)rl.findViewById(R.id.widget29); 
      return rl;
 }
```

}

Then the final class which gets the data from a database and uses the custom adapter to display the information. Does anyone know how i would call each button?

```
`public class SatMain extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @param cont */
    @Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.satmain);
    dbAdapter db = new dbAdapter(this);
     // button.setOnClickListener(m);
    //---get all titles---
    db.open();
      db.InsertData();

    Cursor c =  db.getSat1();

    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {          
             String pub =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_Artist));
             String pub1 =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(db.KEY_Time));



          results.add(pub + pub1 );
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();

   ListView listProducts;
    customArray ca = new customArray(this, R.layout.button, results);
   listProducts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
   listProducts.setAdapter(ca);
    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();      

}
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "getView" method of your adapter, you should set an onClick listener for the button.  You can do an anonymous class so that you can refer to the contents of the row in the button.  I.e, add the following where you get b1 in your example.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //create activity based on prod
        }
   });
```

Comment: and of course you can differentiate between the buttons based on the value of "position"